# Term for pairs of vowels such as А & Я, Е & Є, etc

Tags: граматика, означення

Words ending in either vowel are often treated similarly in a grammatical sense, so I assume that there would be a term for something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As Follower said](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1122/4), the fact that *Я*, *Є*, *Ї*, *Ю* can start with the [j] sound is called “[iotation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotation)”=“[йотація](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)”. (And the *Я*, *Є*, *Ї*, *Ю* themselves are called “iotified letters/vowels”=“йотовані літери/голосні”.)

There is no way to characterize the *А*→*Я*, *Е*→*Є*, *І*→*Ї*, *У*→*Ю* relation with a single word.

However, you can use “iotified counterpart”=“йотований відповідник” to describe, what is *Я* for *А*:

> Йотованим відповідником для «А» є «Я», «О» ж не має йотованої літери-відповідника.
>   An iotofied counterpart for “А” is “Я”; but “О” has no correspondent iotified letter.

Accordingly, you can use “non-iotified counterpart”=“нейотований відповідник” to describe, what is *А* for *Я*. And “a/the ‘iotified-noniotified’ pair”=“пара «йотований-нейотований»” to describe the “А-Я”-like pairs.

Answer (score 7):

I think, it is [**iotation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotation) ([йотація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)). In this case, term for pairs of this vowels is *iotified vowels* (йотовані голосні).

About words ending and their grammatical sense: ([Ukranian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_grammar#Nouns))[declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension) [[відміна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0)].

Answer (score 0):

Diphthong або "дифтонг" in Ukrainian, is a compound vowel. You can also have tripthongs or trigraphs as well with compound of three vowels. [phonetics citation](http://www.phonicsontheweb.com/vowel-combinations.php) I don't know if a specific term for the Ukrainian й-compounds exists, but that would be the general term for a compound vowel.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші відповіді. Цей допис не відповідає таким критеріям: він дуже короткий та не містить посилань на джерела що підтверджують відповідь. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь натиснувши посилання [edit].

Comment: До того ж питання не про поєднання А та Я, а саме про те, що є спільного у пар А-Я, Е-Є, У-Ю, тощо.